# 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, flutter-ios

FYI, I'm on a mac M1. I can run my Flutter app fine from XCode (using my Qa scheme or my Dev scheme, not my Runner scheme though - I get pretty much the same error as below when I try to run my "Runner" default flutter scheme), but not from the terminal. From the terminal I get this:

```
flutter run --dart-define FLAVOR=qa --flavor qa

Launching lib/main.dart on Benji’s iPhone XS in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 5256E329AM
Running pod install...                                           2,969ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                      1,997ms
Xcode build done.                                           13.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-03-21 07:09:47.507 xcodebuild[52458:2092009] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in
    com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-03-21 07:09:47.508 xcodebuild[52458:2092009] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-03-21 07:09:47.715 xcodebuild[52458:2092009] warning:  The file reference for "Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig" is a member of
    multiple groups ("Pods-Runner" and "Pods-Runner"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the
    groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more
    than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2022-03-21 07:09:47.715 xcodebuild[52458:2092009] warning:  The file reference for "Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig" is a member
    of multiple groups ("Pods-Runner" and "Pods-Runner"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the
    groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more
    than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2022-03-21 07:09:47.715 xcodebuild[52458:2092009] warning:  The file reference for "Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig" is a member
    of multiple groups ("Pods-Runner" and "Pods-Runner"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the
    groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more
    than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/37/zgg8z2yj5sq03glqv_2sygn80000gn/T/flutter_tools.ebG04t/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirPRh7CC/temporary_xcresult_bun
        dle

    /var/folders/37/zgg8z2yj5sq03glqv_2sygn80000gn/T/SchemeScriptAction-hmXygb.sh: line 14: /qa.xcconfig: Read-only file system
    /Users/benjaminfarquhar/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.8.4+10/ios/Classes/FLTPHPickerSa
    veImageToPathOperation.m:126:9: warning: 'requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler:' is deprecated: first deprecated in
    iOS 13 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            requestImageDataForAsset:originalAsset
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            requestImageDataAndOrientationForAsset
    In module 'Photos' imported from
    /Users/benjaminfarquhar/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.8.4+10/ios/Classes/FLTImagePicke
    rPhotoAssetUtil.h:6:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Framewor
    ks/Photos.framework/Headers/PHImageManager.h:162:1: note: 'requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler:' has been
    explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (PHImageRequestID)requestImageDataForAsset:(PHAsset *)asset options:(nullable PHImageRequestOptions *)options
    resultHandler:(void (^)(NSData *_Nullable imageData, NSString *_Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary
    *_Nullable info))resultHandler
    API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("-requestImageDataAndOrientationForAsset:options:resultHandler:", ios(8, 13), tvos(8, 13))
    API_UNAVAILABLE(macos);
    ^
    1 warning generated.
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/benjaminfarquhar/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.8.4+10/ios/Classes/FLTImagePicke
    rPhotoAssetUtil.m:17:44: warning: 'UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Will be
    removed in a future release, use PHPicker. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      NSURL *referenceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
                                               ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Framewor
    ks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIImagePickerController.h:62:51: note: 'UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL' has been explicitly
    marked deprecated here
    UIKIT_EXTERN UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey const UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL API_DEPRECATED("Will be removed in a
    future release, use PHPicker.", ios(4.1, 11.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos); // an NSURL that references an asset in the
    AssetsLibrary framework
                                                      ^
    /Users/benjaminfarquhar/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.8.4+10/ios/Classes/FLTImagePicke
    rPhotoAssetUtil.m:21:47: warning: 'fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11 - Will be
    removed in a future release [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[ referenceURL ]
                                                  ^
    In module 'Photos' imported from
    /Users/benjaminfarquhar/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.8.4+10/ios/Classes/FLTImagePicke
    rPhotoAssetUtil.h:6:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Framewor
    ks/Photos.framework/Headers/PHAsset.h:77:1: note: 'fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:' has been explicitly marked deprecated
    here
    + (PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *)fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)assetURLs options:(nullable PHFetchOptions
    *)options API_DEPRECATED("Will be removed in a future release", ios(8, 11), tvos(8, 11)) API_UNAVAILABLE(macos);
    ^
    2 warnings generated.
    error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
    CompileC
    /Users/benjaminfarquhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fthfjngncvusindjscndkyoymshq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Po
    ds.build/Release-iphoneos/geolocator_apple.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GeolocatorPlugin.o
    /Users/benjaminfarquhar/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_apple-2.1.1+1/ios/Classes/Geolocator
    Plugin.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'geolocator_apple' from project
    'Pods')
    /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController
    .m:87:14: warning: 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Use UIScrollView's
    contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
                 ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Framewor
    ks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:257:34: note: 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' has been explicitly marked
    deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets API_DEPRECATED("Use UIScrollView's
    contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior instead", ios(7.0,11.0),tvos(7.0,11.0)); // Defaults to YES
                                     ^
    /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController
    .m:1281:40: warning: 'UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 - Use -[UIDevice
    userInterfaceIdiom] directly. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                        && UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone;
                                           ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Framewor
    ks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIDevice.h:99:36: note: 'UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    static inline UIUserInterfaceIdiom UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() API_DEPRECATED("Use -[UIDevice userInterfaceIdiom] directly.",
    ios(2.0, 13.0), tvos(9.0, 11.0)) {
                                       ^
    /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController
    .m:1299:36: warning: 'topLayoutGuide' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor
    instead of topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                statusBarHeight = self.topLayoutGuide.length;
                                       ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Framewor
    ks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:500:58: note: 'topLayoutGuide' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) id<UILayoutSupport> topLayoutGuide API_DEPRECATED("Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor
    instead of topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor", ios(7.0,11.0), tvos(7.0,11.0));
                                                             ^
    3 warnings generated.
    <module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
    #import "Firebase.h"
            ^
    /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/ios/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources/Firebase.h:15:9: error:
    'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
    #import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
            ^
    /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:3:8: error: could not build Objective-C module
    'Firebase'
    import Firebase
           ^
    remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/benjaminfarquhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fthfjngncvusindjscndkyoymshq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/R
    unner.build/release-qa-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-6A5F72254181C2B460C203FF.sh'


    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/37/zgg8z2yj5sq03glqv_2sygn80000gn/T/flutter_tools.ebG04t/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirPRh7CC/temporary_xcresult_bun
        dle


Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Uncategorized (Xcode): Exited with status code 1


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/ios/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources/Firebase.h:14:8


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'
/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:2:7



Error launching application on Benji’s iPhone XS.
```

I assume that running from the terminal must run my "Runner" scheme. So maybe the solution will be to somehow run my app from the terminal and choose my "dev" and "qa" scheme??

Why do I get this error? I've tried everything. Pod deintegrate, pod install, rosetta terminal, delete derived data, re-dragging googleservices-info.plist into the xcode project etc... I'm hoping the fact that it works when running from Xcode when not using the Runner scheme will shed some light on this issue.